# Tick color dynamic not working - ChartJs + QuickChart

Tags: chart.js, quickchart

I am trying to set the color of the y ticks in my chart js dynamicaly, but facing some issues with the quickchart api. In charts directly it works, but using quickchart it throws an error:

this is what i'm trying to do:

```
{
      type: "line",
      data: {
          labels: ['A', 'B'],
          datasets: [
              {
                  label: "Previsto Acumulado",
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,112,192,1)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(0,112,192,1)",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  data: [90, 100],
              },
              {
                  label: "Realizado Acumulado",
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,176,80,1)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(0,176,80,1)",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  data: [70, 20],
              },
          ],
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              y: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  max: (context) =>{
                    var meta = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data
                    var real = context.chart.data.datasets[1].data
                    var max_bar_value = Math.max(...[Math.max(...meta), Math.max(...real)])
                    return Math.ceil( 1.2*max_bar_value)
                },
                  ticks: {
                      callback: function (value) {
                          return value + "%";
                      },
                      font: {
                            weight: "bold",
                            size: 15,
                        },
                        color: (c)=>{c.tick.value > 100 ? 'white' : 'black'}
                  },
              },
              x: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        weight: "bold",
                        size: 15,
                    }
                },
            }
          },
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                color: (context)=> {
                  return context.dataset.backgroundColor
                  },
                offset: function(context) {
                    return context.dataset.label === 'Realizado Acumulado' ? 5 : 15;
                  },
                  font: {
                      weight: "bold",
                      size: '16'
                      },
                formatter: function(value) {
                    return (Math.round(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
                },
            },
          },
      },
  }
```

the error is on the color: `(c)=>{c.tick.value > 100 ? 'white' : 'black'}` statement. I have no idea why it's broken, the error that chart js returns is 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

I am using sandbox of quickcharts, here is the [LINK](https://quickchart.io/sandbox#%7B%22chart%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20type%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%5Cn%20%20data%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27January%27%2C%20%27February%27%2C%20%27March%27%2C%20%27April%27%2C%20%27May%27%2C%20%27June%27%2C%20%27July%27%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27line%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Dataset%201%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%27rgb(54%2C%20162%2C%20235)%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderWidth%3A%202%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B-33%2C%2026%2C%2029%2C%2089%2C%20-41%2C%2070%2C%20-84%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Dataset%202%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%27rgb(255%2C%2099%2C%20132)%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B-42%2C%2073%2C%20-69%2C%20-94%2C%20-81%2C%2018%2C%2087%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%27white%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderWidth%3A%202%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Dataset%203%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%27rgb(75%2C%20192%2C%20192)%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B93%2C%2060%2C%20-15%2C%2077%2C%20-59%2C%2082%2C%20-44%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20options%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20true%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27My%20chart%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20scales%3A%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ticks%3A%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%27red%27%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A300%2C%22version%22%3A%222.9.4%22%7D) just copy paste my code

Thanks